# multi tasking in android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

i get the Choreographer error The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
In my main activity each time i launch the app or get back to the main activity.

From what i understand there's to many work to be done on one core (because i'm not using threads), so i have to find a solution which probably evolves threads and AsyncTask.

I was trying to figure out what exactly cause the cpu put his effort but i couldn't figure it out by myself.

Here's the code of the main activity which includes a navigation drawer:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
    implements View.OnClickListener {


private Animation animAlpha;
private Animation animRotate;

private MediaPlayer background_music;

static int is_login = 0;

private boolean isOpen = false;

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private CharSequence mTitle;

private ViewFlipper flipper;

ImageButton messages,weekly_day_times,shabat_times,events;

private ViewGroup mContainerView1,mContainerView2,mContainerView3,mContainerView4;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    animAlpha = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anim_alpha);
    animRotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anim_rotate);

    background_music = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.yedid_nefesh);

    flipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper);
    startFlipper();

    background_music.start();

    messages = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.messages_button);
    weekly_day_times = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.weekly_times_button);
    shabat_times = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sat_times_button);
    events = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.events_button);

    messages.setOnClickListener(this);
    weekly_day_times.setOnClickListener(this);
    shabat_times.setOnClickListener(this);
    events.setOnClickListener(this);

    mContainerView1 = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.add_shabat_container);
    mContainerView2 = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.add_weekly_container);
    mContainerView3 = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.add_messages_container);
    mContainerView4 = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.add_events_container);

    findViewById(R.id.b_shabat_add).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.b_weekly_add).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.b_messages_add).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.b_events_add).setOnClickListener(this);

    IntializeNavDrawer();

}

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    setButtonsAnimation(messages);
    setButtonsAnimation(weekly_day_times);
    setButtonsAnimation(shabat_times);
    setButtonsAnimation(events);
}

private void setButtonsAnimation(ImageButton button) {

    int rand = (int)(Math.random()*700);
    Animation hyperspaceJump = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.hyperspace_jump);
    hyperspaceJump.setStartOffset(rand);
    button.startAnimation(hyperspaceJump);
}

/*
    Initialize all list views in navigation drawer.
    Handles actions of open or close drawer.
     */
private void IntializeNavDrawer() {

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);


    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
            GravityCompat.START);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            null, R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
            // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
            // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}

/*
Initialize properties and start the background flipper
 */
private void startFlipper() {

    flipper.setFlipInterval(5000);
    flipper.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            android.R.anim.fade_in));
    flipper.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            android.R.anim.fade_out));
    flipper.startFlipping();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    flipper.startFlipping();
    background_music.start();
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {



        Intent i;
        switch(v.getId())

        {

            case R.id.messages_button: {
                i = new Intent(com.example.neotavraham.MainActivity.this, Messages.class);
                startActivity(i);
                return;
            }
            case R.id.sat_times_button: {
                i = new Intent(com.example.neotavraham.MainActivity.this, ShabatPrays.class);
                startActivity(i);
                return;
            }
            case R.id.weekly_times_button: {

                i = new Intent(com.example.neotavraham.MainActivity.this, WeeklyPrays.class);
                startActivity(i);
                return;
            }
            case R.id.events_button: {
                i = new Intent(com.example.neotavraham.MainActivity.this, Events.class);
                startActivity(i);
                return;
            }
            case R.id.b_shabat_add:
                if(isOpen){
                    removeItem(mContainerView1);
                    isOpen = false;
                }else {
                    addItem(mContainerView1,R.layout.nav_drawer_l_changes_item_1);
                    isOpen =true;
                }
                return;
            case R.id.b_weekly_add:
                if(isOpen){
                    removeItem(mContainerView2);
                    isOpen = false;
                }else {
                    addItem(mContainerView2,R.layout.nav_drawer_l_changes_item_1);
                    isOpen =true;
                }
                return;
            case R.id.b_messages_add:
                if(isOpen){
                    removeItem(mContainerView3);
                    isOpen = false;
                }else {
                    addItem(mContainerView3,R.layout.nav_drawer_l_changes_item_2);
                    isOpen =true;
                }
                return;
            case R.id.b_events_add:
                if(isOpen){
                    removeItem(mContainerView4);
                    isOpen = false;
                }else {
                    addItem(mContainerView4,R.layout.nav_drawer_l_changes_item_2);
                    isOpen =true;
                }
                return;
     }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
    // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    background_music.pause();
    flipper.stopFlipping();
}

/**** Method for Setting the Height of the ListView dynamically.
 **** Hack to fix the issue of not showing all the items of the ListView
 **** when placed inside a ScrollView  ****/
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter == null)
        return;

    int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    int totalHeight = 0;
    View view = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        view = listAdapter.getView(i, view, listView);
        if (i == 0) {
            view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(desiredWidth, AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }

        view.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        totalHeight += view.getMeasuredHeight();
    }
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();
}

private void addItem(ViewGroup mContainerView,int layout) {
    // Instantiate a new "row" view.
    final ViewGroup newView = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(
            layout, mContainerView, false);

    // Because mContainerView has android:animateLayoutChanges set to true,
    // adding this view is automatically animated.
    mContainerView.addView(newView, 2);
}

public void removeItem(ViewGroup mContainerView){
    mContainerView.removeViewAt(2);
}



@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
}
```

Also here are puctures with and withougt the navigation bar:

[image]

[image]

I was hoping you will show me what cuase to that error and an example on how should i get over it.

thank you

Comment: Use Traceview and `StrictMode` to learn where your problems are.

Comment: @CommonsWare, believe me i will, but right now i don't have much time and i really need your help..

Comment: Then perhaps you ought to start using TraceView and `StrictMode` **right now**.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some information from the Android documentation site about multi-threading.
https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/index.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/commontasks.html#threading

You can look around the web for more tutorials.